# Copy folders only with numeric names

Tags: regular-expression, directory, scp

Lets assume we have a directory `/dir/` which contains lots of folders. Some of the folder names are numeric like `1, 2, 64346, 2353, 3` etc. Some contain classical names `some_name, some_other_name, another_name` etc. How can I copy from remote to local host only directory that have only numbers in their name?

I'm looking for something like `scp -r username@host:/dir/[all_numerical_names] .`

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Are `foo12`, `foo12bar` and `12foo` numeric or not? Should this be directories whose entire name consists of nothing but numbers or do you want any directory with at least one number it its name?

Comment: yes, the names consists of nothing but numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to match remote file/directory names against a criterion such as being entirely numeric. However, since you're using `scp` it seems reasonable to assume `ssh` is also available. On that basis here's how I would consider solving the problem:

```
rhost="user@remoteHost"    # Fix as appropriate
rpath="/dir"               # Likewise

ssh -qn "$rhost" "find '$rpath' -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0" |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' item
        do
            if [[ "$item" =~ ^(.*/)?[0-9]+$ ]]
            then
                # Numeric directory
                echo "Copying $item" >&2            # Optional
                scp -r "$rhost":"$rpath/$item" .    # Maybe -a instead of -r
            fi
        done
```

Caveats

- Requires GNU `find` on the remote system (for `-print0`)
- Requires `bash` on the local system (for `read` and the RE comparison)
- Certificate based authentication is strongly recommended (so that a password is not repeatedly required)
- `$rpath` must not contain either double or single quotes

If you don't have GNU `find` on the remote system you can replace `-print0` with `-print` and then adjust the `read -r -d '' item` to become simply `read -r item`. However, it may then perform unexpectedly with "strange" directory names such as `$'123\ntext\n456'` that should be excluded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a high quality answer. Didn't expect it. I do have the requirements except a certificate. A passphrase is required. Is it possible to build it in?

Comment: @JürgenK you should be able to create an ssh certificate pair that requires no passphrase. Of course you may prefer not to do that, in which case I believe that an "ssh agent" may be able to help (but I've not done that myself)